# Я ограничен тэгом <style>, могу ли я как-то добавить фоновую музыку в дизайн странички и вообще "развернуться"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, frontend

Не взламывая ничего, естественно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А через style музыка и не добавляется. Тут нужен нег audio

```
<audio autoplay>    
    <source src="audio/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">    
</audio>
```

вставляете его в html и прячете. Можно добавить атрибут preload для загрузки файла вместе с загрузкой веб-страницы